# Efficient solution for forward filling missing values in a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I need to forward fill values in a column of a dataframe within groups. I should note that the first value in a group is never missing by construction. I have the following solutions at the moment.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,2,2,2], 'b': [1, np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan]})

# desired output
a   b
1   1
1   1
2   2
2   2
2   2
```

Here are the three solutions that I've tried so far.

```
# really slow solutions
df['b'] = df.groupby('a')['b'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill'))
df['b'] = df.groupby('a')['b'].fillna(method='ffill')

# much faster solution, but more memory intensive and ugly all around
tmp = df.drop_duplicates('a', keep='first')
df.drop('b', inplace=True, axis=1)
df = df.merge(tmp, on='a')
```

All three of these produce my desired output, but the first two take a really long time on my data set, and the third solution is more memory intensive and feels rather clunky. Are there any other ways to forward fill a column?

Comment: Is your real data sorted by group, as the example data is?  If so, you should be able to just to a regular `ffill` since your first value in a group is always present, i.e. `df['b'] = df['b'].ffill()`.

Comment: Wow. I completely missed that. After sorting it's lightning fast. Thanks @root!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to sort by both columns `df.sort_values(['a', 'b']).ffill()` to ensure robustness.  If an `np.nan` is left in the first position within a group, `ffill` will fill that with a value from the prior group.  Because `np.nan` will be placed at the end of any sort, sorting by both `a` and `b` ensures that you will not have `np.nan` at the front of any group.  You can then `.loc` or `.reindex` with the initial index to get back your original order.

This will obviously be a tad slower than the other proposals... However, I contend it will be **correct** where the others are not.

***demo***

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,2,2,2], 'b': [1, np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan]})

print(df)

   a    b
0  1  1.0
1  1  NaN
2  2  NaN
3  2  2.0
4  2  NaN
```

Try

```
df.sort_values('a').ffill()

   a    b
0  1  1.0
1  1  1.0
2  2  1.0  # <--- this is incorrect
3  2  2.0
4  2  2.0
```

Instead do

```
df.sort_values(['a', 'b']).ffill().loc[df.index]

   a    b
0  1  1.0
1  1  1.0
2  2  2.0
3  2  2.0
4  2  2.0
```

***special note***
This is still incorrect if an entire group has missing values

Answer (score 2):

Using ffill() directly will give the best results. Here is the comparison

```
%timeit df.b.ffill(inplace = True)
best of 3: 311 µs per loop

%timeit df['b'] = df.groupby('a')['b'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill'))
best of 3: 2.34 ms per loop

%timeit df['b'] = df.groupby('a')['b'].fillna(method='ffill')
best of 3: 4.41 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

what about this

```
df.groupby('a').b.transform('ffill')
```